# Whatsapp like user profile layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, wear-os

I'm new to android custom UI. How can I make profile layout like whatsapp ?

[image]

Background is gray that is okay. But how they created white box partitions ? How they added text in that?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I checked card view but it is not supporting older devices. Any alternative ?

Answer (score 2):

Background is gray that is okay. But how they created white box partitions ? How they added text in that?

=> That's **[`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)**, which is given in support library. Wrap your layout code with `CardView` tags.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 // include your layout code here

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: @JayRaval Google.com!

Comment: @JayRaval what do you mean by older devices? You mean providing compatibility to lower android OS versions?

Comment: yes. lower android API level

Comment: @JayRaval check the [Using the Support library](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html#SupportLib) of Maintaining Compatibility documentation!